# How to pass a string into glutCreateWindow() function?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am reading a name from a file which I then use to name the window. However, it will not allow me to do that since it requires an ASCII character string . I can however do something like this directly

```
glutCreateWindow("StackOverflow").
```

Isn't this also a ASCII character string? Why am I able to do this but not something like this:

```
string x = "stack";
glutCreateWindow(x);
```

Is there a way to cast "x" to meet my needs?

Comment: The type of the parameter of `glutCreateWindow` is `const char *`. So it has to be `const char *x = "stack";` `glutCreateWindow(x);`. Or `std::string x = "stack";` `glutCreateWindow(x.c_str());`. See [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). But that is very basic c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`std::string::c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method:

```cpp
std::string x = "stack";
glutCreateWindow(x.c_str());
```